# How to format a timestamp in python to a readable format?

Tags: python, python-3.x, time

I have a slack bot that gets schedule information and prints the start and end times of the user's schedule. I am trying to format the timestamp so that it is a more readable format. Is there a way to format this response?

Here is an example of the output:

```
co = get_co(command.split(' ')[1])
start = get_schedule(co['group'])['schedule']['schedule_layers'][0]['start']
end = get_schedule(co['group'])['schedule']['schedule_layers'][0]['end']
response = 'Start: {} \n End: {}'.format(start,end)
```

The current time format is `2019-06-28T15:12:49-04:00`, but I want it to be something more readable like `Fri Jun 28 15:12:49 2019`

Comment: Not sure why you tagged Slack to this answer. Is there any relevance?

Comment: I think 'arrow' has many options

Comment: @ErikKalkoken My code is for a slack app. CodeIt solved my problem. I guess the tag is unnecessary I'll remove it if it's an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [dateparser](https://pypi.org/project/dateparser/) to parse the date time string easily.

```
import dateparser

date = dateparser.parse('2019-06-28T15:12:49-04:00') # parses the date time string

print(date.strftime('%a %b %d %H:%m:%M %Y'))
# Fri Jun 28 15:06:12 2019
```

See this in action [here](https://repl.it/repls/ProudFluidSdk)

Answer (score 0):

To convert timestamps of any format you can use the datetime module as described here:

https://stackabuse.com/converting-strings-to-datetime-in-python/

Comment: Hey and welcome to SO. Thanks for your contribution, but please note that link only answers are usually not that helpful, because links may become invalid over time. Instead please always also provide the relevant details in the answer. Thanks!